# past perfect to explain the completion of an action

Tags: past-perfect

> I just ordered the book after seeing this aleatorick's  post on the blog (probably as soon as he **had posted** it)

would it be better to use past simple for post, I chose past perfect because I wanted to explain the completion of the action  of posting (he had just finished writing it that I was already ordering  it)

Comment: IMHO there is nothing wrong with what you have written. I can't detect any errors. It's completely understandable. Also, I would say you could use either "had posted" or "posted".  It really makes little difference here in this particular example.

Answer (score 0):

> I just ordered the book after seeing this aleatorick's post on the blog (probably as soon as he had posted it).

'just ordered' is usually used in the sense of 'I ordered it just a few seconds ago', which is not necessarily what you intend to convey. It would be better to move 'just' to a position where it will do more good, e.g.:

> I ordered the book as soon as I read aleatorick's post on the blog (probably just after he posted it)

NOTE:

'as soon as I read'  - i.e., you read the post and immediately ordered the book. "Read' is better than 'seeing' if you want to indicate that it was the contents of the post that caused you to order the book, not simply the mere existence of the post.

'just after he posted it' - past perfect is not really needed as it is quite clear from the context that the reading occurred right after the posting. It is best to use simple tenses where possible, and limit more complex tenses to situations where they are really needed.

Comment: But I posted this comment on the blog a few seconds after reading and ordering, that is why I use just.  These actions were almost done simultaneously read, ordered and posted

Comment: I have no doubt that you meant that the three actions (read, order, post) occurred almost simultaneously, but someone reading your sentence could arrive at a different conclusion. If I say 'I just saw The MEG after seeing it advertised on television', you know I just saw the movie, but you have no idea how long ago I saw the advertisement on TV. Your sentence tells us that you read aleatorick's post almost as soon as he posted it; it tells us that you have just ordered a book he mentions; but it does not tell us how much time past between you reading his post and ordering the book.

Comment: That is why I changed your sentence to say, 'I ordered the book as soon as I read aleatorick's post'. We now know that you ordered the book 'as soon as' you read the post. '[J]ust ordered' tells us how recently you ordered the book, not how recently you read the post.

Answer (score 0):

I searched about usage as soon as

(1) I'll lend you the book as soon as I **have done** with it

(2) As soon as is used in past sentence : I just ordered the book as soon as he **posted** it.

(3) When we want to use perfect form, then we have :

No sooner **had** he **posted** it than I just ordered the book.

(2) and (3) share the same meaning.